# Distance to outside lables in MS Chart

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visualization, mschart

I'm trying to reduce distance between outside labels in MS Chart (Pie) and actual pie. The lines are really long and making my chart very small. 
Is there a way to position these labels closer?[image: current look]

Thank you

```
Chart2.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
Chart2.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Inclination = 70;
Chart2.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
Chart2.Series[0]["3DLabelLineSize"] = "35";
Chart2.Series[0]["MinimumRelativePieSize"] = "70";
```

Comment: Just browsed the documentation came across the [3DLabelLineSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456633%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) custom property.  I'm not familiar with the property myself, but it looks like it may be what you want.

Comment: thank you for trying, but does not work

Comment: it's always better to put your code in order to get faster answers.

Comment: with Chart Pie I think it's a good way to put the labels into the chart, your graph is easily understandable.